# Extract text not surrounded by hrefs

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, href

I must extract all the text from a `<p>`.

This paragraph is full of links, so it is very easy to extract the text, by using this expression:

```
//div[@class="content clearfix"]/p[2]//a/text()
```

Problem is sometimes, from the same paragraph, I also need to extract text that is not linked, eg.

```
<p>
<a href=“url”>text1</a>,
text2,
<a href=“url”>text3</a>,
<a href=“url”>text4</a>,
<a href=“url”>text5</a>,
<a href=“url”>text6</a>,
<a href=“url”>text7</a>,
text8,
text9
</p>
```

Using the preceding expression I can’t get *text2*, *text8* and *text9*.

If I extract the text this way:

```
//div[@class="content clearfix"]/p[2]//text()
```

I get a mess, because of the unwanted presence of commas, spaces and other characters.

Is there anyway to do what should I do with XPath?

UPDATE: my desidered output is a list like following:

```
["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5", "text6", "text7", "text8", "text9"]
```

Comment: The commas and spaces are part of "all the text". If you don't want them, remove them. Using `replace()`, for example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace. Or a regular expression perhaps.

Comment: @mzjn Of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using normalize-space():

```xml
normalize-space(//div[@class="content clearfix"]/p[2])
```

This will get you close. It would be a string that looks something like this:

```
text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7, text8, text9
```

Then you could split it up by "," (`text` is a variable containing the string above):

```py
split_text = [text_node.strip() for text_node in text.split(",")]
```

Full example...

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<doc>
<div class="content clearfix">
<p>Added to make p[2] in xpath work.</p>
<p>
<a href="url">text1</a>,
text2,
<a href="url">text3</a>,
<a href="url">text4</a>,
<a href="url">text5</a>,
<a href="url">text6</a>,
<a href="url">text7</a>,
text8,
text9
</p>
</div>
</doc>
"""

parsed_xml = etree.fromstring(xml)

text = parsed_xml.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="content clearfix"]/p[2])')

print(text)

split_text = [text_node.strip() for text_node in text.split(",")]

print(split_text)
```

printed output...

```
text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7, text8, text9
['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5', 'text6', 'text7', 'text8', 'text9']
```

Comment: The output is not the desidered one: I need something like ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5", "text6", "text7", "text8", "text9"]. In your output I see ",", "\n", "text8, text9", that are not acceptable in my particular situation

Comment: @LifeafterGuest - Sorry, that wasn't clear to me. Maybe you should update your question with the desired output.

Comment: You're absolutely right: none understood what I wanted, it's my fault, sorry

Comment: This works for me if I modify it a little, getting rid of etree, this way: `parsed_xml = html.fromstring(page.content)`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to essentially ignore the structure *within* the `p` element, and just read all the text of the `p` as if it weren't divided up into `a` elements?

My understanding is that lxml supports the rather ancient version 1.0 of XPath, so your string-processing functions are very limited. My suggestion would be to use an XPath expression to extract the full text of the paragraph, and then tokenize it into an array of strings in the Python layer, by splitting it around the comma characters which you want to ignore. To get the full text of the para in your example as a single string value (i.e. concatenating all the individual text nodes within it), you can use the `string()` XPath function, e.g.

```
string(//div[@class="content clearfix"]/p[2])
```

In later versions of XPath it'd be easy to also tokenize this string *in the XPath expression*, but for XPath 1.0 it's not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

The following can be tried.

```
1. if the element you want to extract does not contain a certain attribute
xpath("//div[@class='content clearfix']/p/a[not(@href)]/text()")


2. If the element you want to extract contains a certain attribute but the values are fixed
xpath("//div[@class='content clearfix']/p/a[not(@href='url')]/text()")

3. Custom match schemes, for example for links you can use the http keyword
xpath("//div[@class='content clearfix']/p/a[not(contains(@href, 'http'))]/text()")
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Problem is that a: I want to get the text that is not surrounded by "a" tags, but I couldn't find a way to do it. Is there any way to select the text in a paragraph that is not "embedded" in a link? I tried your examples, but any of them involves the a tag in a way.

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you want; do you want all the text in the paragraph? Or just the text which isn't enclosed in links? Do you want to retrieve a sequence of individual text nodes or do you just want a string that's the concatenation of all the text nodes?

Comment: do you means like this://div[@class='content clearfix']/p/child::text()? result is ['\n', ',\ntext2,\n', ',\n', ',\n', ',\n', ',\n', ',\ntext8,\ntext9\n']

Comment: @ConalTuohy My goal is to get an array containing text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7, text8, text9

Comment: @maya I tried that, but it results in too much "noise". Maybe I should try regexes or string methods, XPath is not the right tool.

Comment: @LifeafterGuest when you say "an array containing text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7, text8, text9", do you mean like `["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5", "text6", "text7", "text8", "text9"]` i.e. do you want to ignore the commas in the original XML? Or should they part of the strings in your array?

Comment: @ConalTuohy, I want completely ignore the commas, I only need the text. The fact that the original html is list-like  :-)  suggests one could read that html into a string and then try to strip off the tags